# Regexp to remove recursively html in string by class and tag name

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, replace

Can somebody help me on this:

```
console.log('<span class="tooltip">aaaa</span><b>ok</b> <span class="tooltip">bbbb</span>'.replace('/<span .*?class="(.*?tooltip.*?)">(.*?)<\/span>/\g', ''))
```

I would like to remove span tags with class name .tooltip and so this to print in console "**ok**"

Also i would like not to trim the string so if any hidden char is present like `\n` should not be removed.

Comment: Does it need to be a regular expression? It's probably the hardest way to parse HTML.

Comment: can be whatever i just want to strip them out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
const data = '<span class="tooltip">aaaa</span><b>ok</b> <span class="tooltip">bbbb</span>'
const removeTags = data => data.replace(/\s*<span.*?class="tooltip".*?>(.*?)\s*<\/span>\s*/g, '')

console.log(removeTags(data))
```

This will also match multiline:

```js
const data = `<span class="tooltip">aaaa

</span><b>ok</b> <span class="tooltip">bbbb</span>`
const removeTags = data => data.replace(/(?:\s|\n)*<span(?:.|\n)*?class="tooltip"(?:.|\n)*?>(?:[^])*?(?:\s|\n)*<\/span>(?:\s|\n)*/g, '')
console.log(removeTags(data))
```

Comment: I need to remove by tag name and class , the one you show seems to remove any html tag or i am mistaking?

Comment: Yes so what tags you want to remove?

Comment: span with class .tooltip :)

Comment: only this class or other are alowed so `'tooltip black'`

Comment: sorry my bad it should print nothing in console, i go correct my question @Maciej

Comment: @sbaaaang now it's ok ?

Comment: awesome! does this takes into consideration the hidden chars like \n ? I would like to not trim the string in case some of them is present should remain in it

Comment: ok i updated my question thanks a lot then i accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to find them and [.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) to remove them:

```js
var input = '<span class="tooltip">aaaa</span><b>ok</b> <span class="tooltip">bbbb</span>';
var dom = document.createElement("div");
var toRemove;

dom.innerHTML = input;
toRemove = dom.getElementsByClassName("tooltip");
while (toRemove.length > 0) {
  toRemove[0].remove();
}
console.log(dom.innerHTML);
```

For more complex selections you can use, for instance, [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).

This approach admittedly does not use regular expressions but it has the advantage of being easier to maintain and more robust (HTML is not a regular language thus [cannot be reliably parsed with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la#6751339)).